# How can I select certain div inside an element which has other tags

Tags: html, css

I have section tag with 2 divs and 1 img tag inside , how can I select second tag? I tried `section div:nth-child(2)` but it is selecting the second element inside first div , but I want to select second div not first one , **note : I don't want to add class and I did try nth-child in section itself**

```
<section>
   <img src="./somewhere" alt = "something">
    <div>
          <h2>My Page</h2>
          <p> something </p>
     </div>
     <div>
      <button>first btn</button>
      <button> second btn </button>
     </div>
</section>
```

Comment: use 3rd child 'section div:nth-child(3)'

Comment: @ShlokJain wait ... ah damn ! that was syntax error ! , thanks 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:last-of-type` or `:last-child` ([CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)).

```css
section > div:last-child {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="./somewhere" alt = "something">
  <div>
    <h2>My Page</h2>
    <p> something </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>first btn</button>
    <button> second btn </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the 2nd `div` inside `section` you should use
`section div:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: what if I want to select first button inside second div?

Comment: section div:nth-of-type(2) button:first-of-type

Comment: But, I would suggest you to use classes, because it is a good practice.